# How to insert DataSet<Row> ds into cassandra with Java API

Tags: apache-spark-sql, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spark-cassandra-connector

Sample Code needed for Spark Cassandra Connector 2.11-2.0.5, 
Unable to Insert Dataset into cassandra db directly

Comment: You'll need to be a bit more specific.  What exactly have you tried and what error messages are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following Cassandra dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
       <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. set your Cassandra database config details to Spark

   ```
   SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
   sparkConf.setAppName("Spark-Cassandra Integration");
   sparkConf.setMaster("local[4]");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.native.port", "9042");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.rpc.port", "9160");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.timeout_ms", "5000");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms", "200000");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.username", "test_user");
   sparkConf.set("spark.cassandra.auth.password", "test_password");
   ```
3. Creating Spark Context

   ```
   JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
   ```
4. Once you have your RDD, save it to Cassandra database by providing keyspace name & table name

   ```
   CassandraJavaUtil.javaFunctions(userRDD).writerBuilder(keySpaceName, tableName, CassandraJavaUtil.mapToRow(UserBean.class)).saveToCassandra();
   ```

For more details you can check my blog post [Save data to Cassandra tables using Apache Spark](https://khodeprasad.wordpress.com/2016/09/06/save-data-to-cassandra-tables-using-apache-spark/)